# VisualCode - debug console - log so you can click through to source

Tags: logging, dart, visual-studio-code

I have a logger that logs output to the visual code debug console.

The log output includes the file path and line number.

I want to be able to click the file path and have visual code open the appropriate source file.

I note that standard stack traces have the file and line number displayed and you can click through them. However I'm unable to click through the file/line numbers that I log.

e.g.

```
package:myapp/widgets/SplashEffect.dart:24:
```

Answer (score 0):

VS Code doesn't know what `package:` is so is unable to link it. There's also no API for extensions to contribute link detection so we can't handle this from the Dart extension. There are some relevant issues here:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/39063
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34026

If you can output paths relative to the workspace folder, I think that would work.

Comment: For the stack trace the debug adapter gets to provide the paths to VS Code. For the debug console, we can neither tell VS Code which text is links to files, not tell it how to parse links out itself (that's the API bit I mentioned), it just does basic parsing of the text itself.

I edited the relevant VS Code issue links into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found I could do the following:

file:////home/me/git/myapp/lib/widgets/Dashlet.dart:121:9

I don't particularly like this format as its rather verbose, a relative path would have been better but I had trouble getting that to work.

If I use

```
 file:///./lib/test/LogTest.dart:7:9
```

The visual code attempts to access the file '/lib/test/LogTest.dart'.

This doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your solution, logging the path as an Uri worked for me.

```
console.log(`${vscode.Uri.file(filepath)}:${line}:${col}`);
```